# How to mute only back panel audio?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I have a desktop PC where the front and the back panel are available. Usually the front is for headphone while the back for speakers. This PC's headphone detection is not working so I need to create a script to switch between speaker and headphone.

[image: Alsamixer Configuration]

The problem is, while using `alsamixer`, I can't find any way to mute the back panel audio only. It always mute both (front & back) or mute just the headphone (front). I have switched between `snd_hda_intel`'s models (`3stack`, `3stack-automute`, `min_fp`, etc) but cannot see any config in the `alsamixer` dubbed like "Back Speaker".

Any idea?

Comment: Isn't "Front" actually the green port at the back?

Comment: Is it? Seems I have plugged my headphone in the CPU front and it is affected by the Headphone bar. Then both (front and back) are affected by the Front bar in `alsamixer` above.

Comment: Hmm that's unfortunate. Does lowering the PCM bar to 0 make a difference?

Comment: It affects both unfortunately.. The other volume bars (output) either affect neither or both